# how to get n save foreign keys in database using laravel 5.2?

Tags: php

m doing FYP using laravel 5.2 framework.. the issue m facing for the last 2 days is that m not able to get foreign key from database.... actually i want to assign project to employee. for it i require employee-id as a foreign key in project table so that i assign project to employees but i dnt know how to get id from user table n then saves record according to it... kindly help me......

i have alraedy fetch th record but dnt know now how to save that key....here is my code.........
[here its not going to get emp_id as a foreign key...[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHr73.jpg)

controller is here....
 public function assign_edit($id)
   {

```
  $projects=project::find($id);
      $data=array("pagetitle" => "Admin Dashboard | Assign");
  return view('admin.layouts.prjct.assign',$data,['projects'=>$projects]);
```

}

public function assign_update(Request $request,$id)
   {

```
$projects=project::all();

// $projects=project::find($id);
 $projects->project_title= $request->project_title ;
  $projects->project_code = $request->project_code ;
   $projects->project_mgr = $request->project_mgr;
    $projects->project_sdate = $request->project_sdate;
     $projects->project_edate = $request->project_edate ;
          $projects->completion_status = $request->completion_status;
         $projects->save();
 // return redirect('show');
 return view('admin.layouts.prjct.assign',$data)->with('projects',$projects);
```

}

view is here...
 
                  Project title
                project_title ?>" required>

```
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Project Manager</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="project_mgr"  pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Enter Project Manager"  value="<?php echo $projects->project_mgr ?>" required>
            </div>

            @foreach($projects as $project) 
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Select Employees</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{$project->user()}}"  pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Employees to be assign"  >
            </div>

              @endforeach
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

please help me.....